# How to change the font size for the whole plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I am trying to change the font size of a plot in matplotlib.

This is what I have tried:

```
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(8,8),layout="tight")
ax = plt.subplot(111)
for item in ([ax.title, ax.xaxis.label, ax.yaxis.label] +
             ax.get_xticklabels() + ax.get_yticklabels()):
    item.set_fontsize(12)
p.plotKip(m,ax=ax,fig=fig,show_mass_loc=False,show_mix_labels=False)
```

[image]

As you can see, the colorbar text remains unchanged. How can I change the text size of the whole plot?